# Activate every loop by clicking a Button VB.Net

Tags: for-loop, vb.net-2010

This is my issue:  I have a loop 1 to 30 that needs to run a iteration every time that I click the button. basically if i click it should run one iteration and wait for the next click to run the second iteration and so on.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    For i = 1 To 30 'go to next iteration only when i click the Button1
      do whatever

    next i


end sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add a form level variable (initialized to the bottom value "1") to hold the loop counter and in the button click do a simple IF check if on the variable to see if it is within the range you want to run for (1-30) and then increment the variable as the last step inside the button click.

Comment: glad you understood what I was saying without any code. It's been three years since I used VB.net. :)